# How can I reinstall QoS Packet Scheduler if it was removed from the winxp installation by nLite?

Tags: windows-xp, qos, nlite

I have a WinXP SP3 installation modified by nLite. This particular installation was stripped off the QoS Packet Scheduler. I was advised to remove QoS because of the overhead it produces or something like that.

Now, I read this [lifehacker post about windows maintenance](http://lifehacker.com/5520447/windows-maintenance-tips-the-good-bad-and-useless), and it says that on the contrary, by doing so I may have done more harm than good:

> Disabling QoS in Windows XP: Rumor had it that Microsoft had permanently tied up 20 percent of your net bandwidth for Windows Update. They didn't, and those who disable QoS, or IPv6, in XP actually end up with some pretty harsh connectivity problems.

I tend to believe this, and now I seek a way to reinstall QoS. I tried to install it by going to network adapter properties -> install -> service, but there is no QoS there.

I have the original, untouched WinXP SP3 cd.

So, is there a way to bring back QoS into my WinXP installation, preferably **without** reinstalling windows from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [download snetcfg](http://www.jsifaq.com/docs/files/76011/snetcfg.zip) and extract it to a folder (e.g. `C:\TempDir`). You can use it as follows:

Uninstall:

```
C:\TempDir\snetcfg.exe -v -u ms_psched
```

Install:

```
C:\TempDir\snetcfg.exe -v -l "C:\Windows\inf\netpschd.inf" -c s -i ms_psched
```

Comment: I think it worked, QoS Packet Scheduler is now listed in network adapter properties. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To reinstall the QoS Packet Scheduler, follow these steps:

1. Right click on the network adapter or connection then select Properties.
2. Click on the Install button (doesn't matter on which service).
3. Select Service in the new window and click on the Add button.
4. Select QoS Packet Scheduler then click OK and OK again.

This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, normally I would tell you to try Add/Remove Programs > Add/Remove Windows Components, but I just went there myself and didn't see the QoS service there.  Try Network Connections > connection properties > Install.

Comment: I already did this. "I tried to install it by going to network adapter properties -> install -> service, but there is no QoS there"

Comment: @Irwin1138: Oops, sorry. Shouldn't post when I'm tired.